# gitlab - push using https, specifying username & password

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push a newly created repository to gitlab. Here's what I did:

1. Create a project in gitlab. Example URL: https://gitlab.example.com/group1/project1.git
2. Initiated a local bare repo:

   ```
   cd ~/projects
   git init --bare ./project1.git
   cd project1.git
   ```

**Question:**

Next step is to push all of my local repo into gitlab. 
But I want to specify username and password using https. How do I change the following to do it?

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.example.com:group1/project1.git
git push --all
git push --tags
```

Comment: in that url, `examples` is your username

Comment: Sorry, `examples` is a group name. Let me edit that question.

Comment: I think all you can do is save your username somewhere but not the password. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Like others mentioned here, ssh is preferred. But for those you want to use just http/https, you can specify credentials like this:

```
git remote add origin https://username:password@gitlab.example.com:group1/project1.git
```

Verified for gitlab 9.0

Note: Please replace '@' symbols in username with '%40' to work this.

Comment: how to replace '&' symbol from my password ?

Comment: '&' I believe is 26, try %26 - not verified

Comment: On gitlab.com the colon had to be changed to a slash to get it to work: ```https://user:pass@gitlab.com/group/project.git```

Answer (score 3):

If you get `fatal: remote origin already exists` error. Check what `origin` is set up and remove it

```
git remote -v
git remote rm origin
```

Add remote origin for https. You can set up `username:password` in url but credentials will be seen plain text in `git remote -v`

```
git remote add origin https://username:passowrd@git.example.com/group1/project1.git
git remote -v
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

I need to use `\` after url and before group instead of `:`, otherwise I get an error `URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`.

If you have special characters in password and get an error `bash: !: event not found`, for example, for '!' use '%21' (google for 'HTML URL encoding reference').

It is possible to add remote without credentials in url

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.example.com/group1/project1.git
git config credential.helper store
git config --list
```

it will prompt for credentials on first login and should not afterwards. `store` option stores credentials same in plain text in `~/.git-credentials`.
On Windows to store credentials in "Credential Manager"

```
 git config credential.helper wincred
```

you can delete `~/.git-credentials` then.
To clear credential helper

```
git config credential.helper ""
```

Answer (score 2):

When you created the repo in gitlab, by deafault it will provide to clone git repo using two protocols, ssh and https. Where in https it will prompt your user credential every time you pull or push.

I prefer to use ssh. Where as in ssh you can push lot of files to repo. In https you have size restriction. Perhaps you want push 4gb files to repo.

**Follow these steps to set ssh as remote:**

```
git remote rm https://gitlab.example.com:group1/project1.git

git remote set-url origin ssh://user@host:1234/srv/git/example
```

**Useful information:**

Worth reading about setting up git remote:

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/