# How do I git push under a different username after a commit?

Tags: git

Similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13103083/13642249), is it possible for a Git repository to prompt for a username before a push? There are several people that use this computer under one user credential, and instead of making it "workstation," we'd like to know who has made a commit for each git push with their respective username. The author for pushing and writing commit messages is the same.

The [option to add the url origin with a password via https is insufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43070129/13642249), and I'd prefer to prompt for a username rather than wrongly having the commit appear as someone else, as mentioned in this [thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/wrong-user-attributed-on-commits/37065).

Comment: Are all these people signing onto that computer with the same credentials, or do they each have their own?

Comment: Only one user, so one credential for system.

Comment: Username used for pushing and commit author are completely separate things, and it's not clear which one you are asking about. If it's the latter, users could just do `git config user.name "Foo Bar"` before committing.

Comment: @1615903 The author for pushing and commit is the same. User for system is irrelevant, but if BOB on Monday made a push and commit, then Joe can make a different push and commit on Tuesday. Are you saying every time when they push that config has to be set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you commit code as a different user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696938/how-do-you-commit-code-as-a-different-user)

Comment: You seem to be confusing the credentials required to push to a server (managed by the server) with the author information tracked with each commit.

Comment: @knittl To clarify, the credentials used when pushing to a remote Git server are separate from the author information tracked with each commit. However, the author information you set does not guarantee to be a valid user within that project/repo. Correct? I could state that the user is Workstation4 and that their email address is workstation4@aol.com, but it would simply be a record of the commit's author and not a legitimate user on the server.

Comment: I misspoke. Server should be Gitlab, not git server.

Comment: Correct, the author information has nothing to do with any user accounts or server credentials.

Comment: Besides setting up an alias, there does not seem to be an already built in method to prompt for commit author.:/

Comment: Create separate user accounts in your OS and have every user log in with their own account. Sharing an account among several users is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

After going down several rabbit holes, I ended up using the [`post-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit) client side hook located in my repo: `[REPO]/.git/hooks/post-commit`. Had to make sure the file `post-commit` did not have an extension and was executable. I figured that this particular strategy worked best for the use case, because it allows the modification of the author to the intended user for each commit,as well as leveraging the git hosting platform's ability to associate the email address with appropriate username. `git push` has several hooks it could invoke, however it was best to catch after the commit message was entered in case a push wasn't assured immediately after. The script below will prompt the user for the author and email address for their commit message (*getting the prompt to work was a little tricky , but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10015707/13642249) helped out*). Since running `git commit` normally will cause a recursion to occur since `post-commit` *cannot affect the outcome of git commit*, a file is created and destroyed to prevent an endless loop after the new environment values are set.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Break out of recursion
recursion_author_flag="RECURSION_FILE"
if test -f $recursion_author_flag; then
  rm $recursion_author_flag
  exit 0
fi

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

# enable user input
exec < /dev/tty

# Prompt for author
read -p "Enter author name: " author

# Prompt for email
read -p "Enter email: " email

# Amend the commit with new author information
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$author"
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$author"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$email"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$email"
touch $recursion_author_flag
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

Comment: So a sledgehammer to crack a nut, eh? You need to configure this hook _per repository_. It is a lot simpler to simply configure the author for this repo: `git config --local user.name '…'` and `git config --local user.email '…'`. Or use [`includeIf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes) to load different configurations depending on your repository paths

Answer (score 0):

First you need to correctly differentiate between `git commit` and `git push`:

- `git commit` creates a new commit in the local repository, recording the user's name and e-mail in the commit
- `git push` is used to sync new local commits/branches to a remote repository - without changing/editing the pushed commits

The only "user" involved in a `git push` are the credentials required to access the server with the remote repository.

So what you are looking for is how to set the correct author (and committer) while `git commit`.

---

As explained in the [man page for `git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_commit_information) this information is taken from

- environment variables (`GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, ...)
- the git configuration items `user.name` and `user.email`
- [from the command line `git commit --author=...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---authorltauthorgt)

where the latter can be configured

- [per repository with `git config user.name ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---local) (i.e., in `[REPO]/.git/config`) or
- [globally with `git config --global user.name ...`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---global) (i.e., per OS user, in `~/.gitconfig`).

So to have different author names while logging in with the same system user you could

1. let your users always commit with the `--author` flag
2. just give each person their own local copy of the repository and configure their respective name with `git config user.name ...` in that directory
3. set the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` etc. environment variables accordingly

From these 1. only works as reliable as your users are to provide the correct `--author` flag with each commit (and merge!). 2. is a good solution as long as you don't need/want to only have a single local repository.

But 3. is probably the best solution for you - if you can set the environment variables reliably. For this you could use, e.g., [`~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) where you could `read` and `export` the `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` etc. from the user - which also only has to be done only once at login and not with every commit.

---

Bonus Tip:

You can set an empty `user.name` and `user.email` in the local repository to prevent commits with incorrect authors when the author is not explicitly specified (with `--author=...` or `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`) - `git` will abort any commit if it can not determine an author name.

Alternatively you can customize this by setting a known default name (e.g., `git config user.name "DEFAULT"`) and using the [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit) to verify that `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` is not `DEFAULT` and otherwise abort the commit with an error message instructing the user how to set the author name correctly:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# pre-commit hook

if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "DEFAULT" ]; then
  echo 'Please first specify your name and e-mail with the following commands:' >&2

  echo 'export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<Your Name>"' >&2
  echo 'export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="<Your E-Mail>"' >&2
  echo 'export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"' >&2
  echo 'export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL"' >&2

  exit 1
fi
```