# git.exe push --progress "origin" main:main fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to push my code to Github with TortoiseGit after I finish my implementation. However,I am encountering this problem.

I've been trying this command in git bash, I was also trying to push with using tortoiseGit and Visual Studio. All don't work as expected.

I've cloned my repository by using HTTPS url from GitHub. In the past few weeks, it works all fine. But, today, I am encountering that I'm not allowed to push back to Github.

```
git.exe push --set-upstream --progress origin main
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/<username>/folder.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/<username>/folder.git (push)
```

I even tried to check if my remote URL is correct or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gitlab - push using https, specifying username & password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069655/gitlab-push-using-https-specifying-username-password)

Comment: As suggested in the answer pointed above: If you have an ssh key you can access GitHub through ssh `git@github.com:username/folder.git`

Comment: @ewokx Hi, that question didn't solve my issue, anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: @LeGEC Hello, it's also not working as well. Thanks for the help.